# Deploy is everytime in progress on AWS opsworks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-opsworks

Deploy is not finished and failed. I tried stop instance but all operation are in progress. What I need do?

[image]

Comment: Have you changed anything related to security groups? It tends to spin forever if it can't connect to what it needs. What's in the logs of the failed tasks? (Click on "Show" link on the right of the screenshot)
Do you use custom cookbooks? Problems in cookbooks could be causing that too.

Comment: I agree with @semirami. I've seen this before when I modified the security group of the instance and turned off access to the internet. Were you able to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the instances in which you are running the command do not have a way to connect to the internet. On rare occasions, this could also indicate that the Opsworks agent is not running, but that is less likely.

Check the firewall settings and outbound internet access. SSH into the machines and try to ping something on the internet.

If you are deploying your app to a private VPC, then you need to add NAT instances so that the instances have internet access.